# Read a line from File and pass it to variable, then proceed to next line (Assembly 8086)

Tags: file, assembly, x86-16

this is my first post so I'm sorry in advance if I did it wrongly (in any ways).
So what I am facing now is, I have a a file (name.txt) and I want to pass the first line to buffer1 , second line to buffer2 and so on.

Extra Info :

1. The maximum line of the file is going to be 10.
2. The maximum length of the string is 27(data)+1(dollar sign)+2(CR LF) or so I think.
3. I created 5 buffer for this example
4. The example of the string is "1washingmachine"
5. name.txt is already created

.

```
.model small  
.stack 64
.data
filename db "name.txt",0
handler dw ?

strPrompt db 10,13,"enter:$"
strInput label byte
max db  28 ;max name is 20 , + 1 for index , 6 for time , 1 for $
act db ?
data db 28 dup ('$')

buffer1 db 30 dup ('$')
buffer2 db 30 dup ('$')
buffer3 db 30 dup ('$')
buffer4 db 30 dup ('$')
buffer5 db 30 dup ('$')
newLine db 10,13

.code   
main proc far       
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.

mov  ax,@data
mov  ds,ax

;CREATE FILE.

mov  ah, 3dh
mov  al, 2
lea  dx, filename
int  21h  

;PRESERVE FILE HANDLER RETURNED.

mov  handler, ax

;READ STRING

MOV AH, 3FH         ; read file 
MOV BX, handler    ; copy handle into BX

MOV CX,30        ; set count to read 28+2
lea dx,buffer1
INT 21H              ; AX = bytes read

MOV AH, 3FH         ; read file 
MOV BX, handler    ; copy handle into BX
MOV CX,30        ; set count to read 28+2
lea dx,buffer2
INT 21H

MOV AH, 3FH         ; read file 
MOV BX, handler    ; copy handle into BX
MOV CX,30        ; set count to read 28+2
lea dx,buffer3
INT 21H

MOV AH, 3FH         ; read file 
MOV BX, handler    ; copy handle into BX
MOV CX,30        ; set count to read 28+2
lea dx,buffer4
INT 21H
MOV AH, 3FH         ; read file 
MOV BX, handler    ; copy handle into BX
MOV CX,30        ; set count to read 28+2
lea dx,buffer5
INT 21H


mov ah,09h
lea dx,buffer1
int 21h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,buffer2
int 21h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,buffer3
int 21h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,buffer4
int 21h
mov ah,09h
lea dx,buffer5
int 21h

;input string to write in file  

mov ah,09h
lea dx,strPrompt
int 21h

mov ah,0ah
lea dx,strInput
int 21h

;WRITE STRING.

mov  ah, 40h
mov  bx, handler
mov ch,0
mov  cl, act  ;STRING LENGTH.
inc cx 
mov  dx, offset data
int  21h

lea dx,newLine
mov bx,handler
mov cx,2
mov ah,40h
int 21h
;CLOSE FILE (OR DATA WILL BE LOST).

mov  ah, 3eh
mov  bx, handler
int  21h      

;FINISH THE PROGRAM.

mov  ax,4c00h
int  21h 
main endp
end main
```

Hopefully someone from StackOverflow can help me with this, either guidance or solution will do !

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Sorry about that, the thing is when I read the bytes to buffer1, I want to make sure that it only reads the first line of the txt file, but with this code, it reads exactly 30 bytes (as programmed). So is there any method for me to read until the end of line for each buffer?
Eg : buffer1 = line 1 , buffer2 = line 2

Comment: Mostly the answer is 'no.' The thing about low level languages is they don't provide a lot of extras (that would make them high level languages). You might create a routine you could `call` that that reads the input into a buffer, 1 character at a time, checking for eol. You would specify the buffer to read into (probably by passing a pointer to the buffer in a register) and you would provide the size of that buffer (in another register) to prevent overruns. There are fancier ways, but that might be the simplest. You could also experiment with redirects and `int21,a` (not sure about this one).

Comment: A slightly more advanced alternative would be to read the entire file into a buffer, then walk the buffer looking for the end of strings (which implicitly marks the start of the next string).  Rather than copying the data into pre-allocated buffers, you could just have pointers to places within your 1 big, file-holding buffer.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thanks ! I will read the entire file into a buffer, I guess that's a lot easier because I know what the file stores.